# error occurred while executing mysql line in java

Tags: java, mysql, selenium-webdriver

This is my code

```
String Dillingdoctor = driver.findElement(By.id("txtProviderName")).getAttribute("value"); 
         ResultSet res2 = st.executeQuery("SELECT user_name FROM user where person_name= "+Dillingdoctor+" ");
         res2.next();
         String Billing_Doctor = res2.getString(1);
         System.out.println(Billing_Doctor);
```

And I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main"
```

`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:`

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Samiee' at line 1

```
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:382)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3593)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3525)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1986)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2140)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2620)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2570)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1474)
        at login.Verification.main(Verification.java:168)
```

May I know what is the reason?

Comment: Formatting would help.

Comment: Please consider using [PreparedStatements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), as your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your SQL line to the below, you were missing ' characters...

```
SELECT user_name FROM user where person_name= '"+Dillingdoctor+"'
```